# How is order determined in the recommended Pokémon list when fighting at a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I go to fight at a gym, they generate a list of Pokémon. I have noticed that it does not go by type effectiveness, or by cp, as I have my vaporeon always get put at the front even though I have higher cp Pokémon in my party, and Pokémon that have better type effectiveness against the opposing Pokémon. So, how is order actually determined for the recommended Pokémon? Is it by total power (combination of stats), health, or something else?

Comment: I would assume health, but I'm not sure on that at the moment.

Comment: @KazWolfe, I double checked, based on the Pokémon I had for recommended last time I fought, and it was Vaporeon (143 hp, 1293 cp), Golem (93 hp, 1050 cp), Arcanine (96 hp, 1133 cp) and I don't remember the other 3.

Comment: Well, that goes that theory. I'll keep looking

Comment: For me it's the team with the highest CP. I usually edit it to take types into account. Maybe it goes for max attack power first, but I can't verify it with my team since max AP = max CP in my top 6.

Comment: I've had the order change depending on the defending Pokemon. I'm assuming there's an actual algorithm that's a little more complicated than "order by the most HP" or "order by the most CP", although CP and perhaps HP are clearly considered.

Comment: It's ***not*** ordered by CP or HP alone.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've seen, it orders them by CP, skipping any that are not at full health. This can be kind of ridiculous when you have a 1000cp Pokemon with 89/90 health, and it suggests a 700cp Pokemon with 68/68 health over it, but this game is not perfect, it just does the best it can.

I'd also guess that the game takes type effectiveness into account, I've seen this happen in training a gym. The game suggested a weaker vaporeon over a stronger flareon, because the first opponent in the gym was a fire-type pokemon. I have no idea if the suggestions are just based on the first opponent or every opponent in the gym though.

Comment: if it was by CP, my 1400 cp arcanine would be first, not my 1200 vaporeon

Comment: If both pokemon are at full health, then I cannot say what the algorithm is that Pokemon Go uses. All I can relate is my personal experience, which does follow the general rule I listed in my answer.

Comment: I can back up @Dragonrage's statement. In my top 6, a Hitmonlee (400 CP) is above my Jolteon (514 CP).

Comment: Maybe the only reason a lower Pokemon is picked before a higher one is because at some point you manually put that lower Pokemon on your team? Not confirmed, just a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I observed that there are some criteria it looks for:

- High cp pokemon have a higher chance to show up
- High remaining hp pokemon have a higher chance to show up, it may suggest pokemon with lower hp as long as its remaining hp is higher than your others
- Tries to counter the pokemon types in the gym
- Does not take DPS, move strength or speed in consideration at all

I'm sure there is a formula, which mixes these variables with different weights. I'm also searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

Bah, humbug. @Ellesedil has provided a counterexample to my speculation. I'll still leave this here in case it's of any use to anybody.

---

I strongly suspect it's ordered simply by Pokemon level. I'm not sure what it does in case of ties, since I don't have enough data on it, but this is a start. This fits both my suggested Pokemon in Gym battles, and yours.

You provided that you have Vaporeon (143 hp, 1293 cp), Golem (93 hp, 1050 cp), Arcanine (96 hp, 1133 cp). From this, it's possible to calculate that your Vaporeon is level 33-36, your Golem is level 29-36, and your Arcanine is level 25-28.

<sup>(Incidentally, your Vaporeon is 44-53% perfect, your Golem is 22-98% perfect, and your Arcanine is 40-69% perfect. I can also tell from this that your trainer level was 17 or 18 when you submitted that comment!)</sup>

Level range can be determined from the stardust cost to level up. Here's one such chart:

```
Level | Stardust Cost | Candy Cost
------+---------------+-----------
1     | 200           | 1
2     | 200           | 1
3     | 200           | 1
4     | 200           | 1
5     | 400           | 1
6     | 400           | 1
7     | 400           | 1
8     | 400           | 1
9     | 600           | 1
10    | 600           | 1
11    | 600           | 1
12    | 600           | 1
13    | 800           | 1
14    | 800           | 1
15    | 800           | 1
16    | 800           | 1
17    | 1000          | 1
18    | 1000          | 1
19    | 1000          | 1
20    | 1000          | 1
21    | 1300          | 2
22    | 1300          | 2
23    | 1300          | 2
24    | 1300          | 2
25    | 1600          | 2
26    | 1600          | 2
27    | 1600          | 2
28    | 1600          | 2
29    | 1900          | 2
30    | 1900          | 2
31    | 1900          | 2
32    | 1900          | 2
33    | 2200          | 2
34    | 2200          | 2
35    | 2200          | 2
36    | 2200          | 2
37    | 2500          | 2
38    | 2500          | 2
39    | 2500          | 2
40    | 2500          | 2
41    | 3000          | 3
42    | 3000          | 3
43    | 3000          | 3
44    | 3000          | 3
45    | 3500          | 3
46    | 3500          | 3
47    | 3500          | 3
48    | 3500          | 3
49    | 4000          | 3
50    | 4000          | 3
51    | 4000          | 4
52    | 4000          | 4
53    | 4500          | 4
54    | 4500          | 4
55    | 4500          | 4
56    | 4500          | 4
57    | 5000          | 4
58    | 5000          | 4
59    | 5000          | 4
60    | 5000          | 4
61    | 6000          | 6
62    | 6000          | 6
63    | 6000          | 6
64    | 6000          | 6
65    | 7000          | 8
66    | 7000          | 8
67    | 7000          | 8
68    | 7000          | 8
69    | 8000          | 10
70    | 8000          | 10
71    | 8000          | 10
72    | 8000          | 10
73    | 9000          | 12
74    | 9000          | 12
75    | 9000          | 12
76    | 9000          | 12
77    | 10000         | 15
78    | 10000         | 15
79    | 10000         | 15
80    | 10000         | 15
```

Additionally, based on your trainer level, you can only power up Pokemon to a certain level. Here's that chart:

```
Trainer | Max Pokemon
Level   | Level
--------+------------
1       | 4
2       | 6
3       | 8
4       | 10
5       | 12
6       | 14
7       | 16
8       | 18
9       | 20
10      | 22
11      | 24
12      | 26
13      | 28
14      | 30
15      | 32
16      | 34
17      | 36
18      | 38
19      | 40
20      | 42
21      | 44
22      | 46
23      | 48
24      | 50
25      | 52
26      | 54
27      | 56
28      | 58
29      | 60
30      | 62
-- below here is speculation --
31      | 64
32      | 66
33      | 68
34      | 70
35      | 72
36      | 74
37      | 76
38      | 78
39      | 80
40      | 82
```

Comment: Interesting, though when I was fighting a gym with a low jolteon first, the golem was put before the vaporeon. so maybe it does something with type effectiveness as well?

Comment: @Dragonrage Hm, I haven't actually noticed type effectiveness ever actually be taken into account for me... but then again I just have a bunch of Pokemon at wildly varying levels. I'd posit that perhaps your Golem and your Vaporeon are the same level, and it breaks ties by type effectiveness? It's hard to tell since I'm not you, and thus I can't find the exact level of your Pokemon :P

Comment: Also, note that this is just speculation, but it fits all the data from myself, my friends that play, and now you.

Comment: How can I find the exact level of the Pokémon? I can do that and add the info into my question.

Comment: @Dragonrage The only way to be certain about the level of your Pokemon is to power it up until the dust cost changes, or to power it up until you can't anymore. (Trainer level determines the max Pokemon level you can have.) I'll add a chart for the second case.

Comment: I'll let you know when I get some candy and can level them up. If you hop in the bridge I can ping you there instead of leaving a ton of comments there.

Comment: @Dragonrage: I've noticed the game putting lower CP/level Pokemon towards a higher ranking in my suggested list based on type effectiveness. I don't know when the game decides type is more important than overall CP/level, but it does appear to do that. I have different level Vaporeon and Lapras, but the game will often swap which one is at the top... and it seemly depends on whatever Pokemon I'll encounter early into the gym match.

Comment: @Ellesedil Keep in mind that lower CP does not necessarily mean lower level, especially across species with different base stats. (For instance, Vaporeon is ridiculously overtuned right now and has much higher CP per level than most other Pokemon, including Lapras.) Is it possible that your Vaporeon and Lapras are actually the same level?

Comment: @Schism: No, it's not possible. My Vaporeon takes 3k dust to level up (and is actually a couple of levels into the 3k dust range) and my Lapras still takes 2.5k. My Vaporeon is a higher level. Having said that, I could be remembering from a time when my Vaporeon was a lower level as I have invested a bit of resources into leveling it up.